# javascript global var being returned as [object Object] in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I hope someone could help me. I am building a web page and am having issues with a global var. Below is my code flow:

Web page:

1. PHP Query builds up an array of world locations with a number of fields

   **world_locations** =

   [{"id":"1","name":"Everest","country":"China / Nepal","mountainRange":"Himalaya","elevationMetres":"8848","elevationFeet":"29029","worldRank":"1","continentRank":"1","category":"Eight-thousander & Seven Summits","firstAscentWhen":"1953","firstAscentByWho":"Edmund Hillary, Tenzing Norgay","longitude":"86.93","latitude":"27.99","otherFactsNotableAscents":"Apa Sherpa holds the record for reaching the summit more times than any other person, 21 times between 10 May 1990 and 11 May 2011. The record for a non-Sherpa is held by American climber and expedition guide Dave Hahn, reaching the summit 14 times betwee","long":"27.985818","lat":"86.923596","image":"images/location_images/Everest.jpg","publishtomap":"1"},

   etc etc

   ];
2. At the very bottom of the page this is placed into a global var:

   **world_locations** = [php] echo json_encode($allLocations); [/php];
3. I then include my javascript:

   [script] type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js" [/script]
4. When I try and access the var **world_locations** in my script.js it is returned as the following:

   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

EDIT: The above is when I do a simple alert(); in the script.js file. What I really need to use the array for is within other functions in script.js.

This was working a couple of months ago and I am unsure if something has changed in the meantime. I have tried jquery-1.8.3.min.js, jquery-1.9.1.min.js, jquery-1.10.1.min.js and jquery-2.0.2.min.js with no change.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do an alert?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong, yes, it is an array of objects, what do you expect ?

Comment: Yes Satpal, this is me alerting the world_locations but surely I should see the actual content?!

Comment: Hi DavidLin, I was expecting to see the actual content as I mention above and not just [object Object] or am I being stupid!

Comment: You probably changed PHP that was reading the array. Try accessing an individual property like array[ 'country' ]

Comment: use console.dir(object) to see the real object instead of "[object, Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `alert(world_locations[0].name)` and you can see that your object is indeed defined as you want ;)

If you want to check the entire object, try `alert(JSON.stringify(world_locations))` to convert the object to a JSON string you can read, rather than the built-in `toString` function (which just returns `[object Object]`)